# When is UITableView finished updating?

Tags: iphone, sdk

My problem seems quite simple but I have failed to find a solution here or elsewhere. 
I have a `UITableView` as a subclass in one of my UIViews. When the application finishes the last selected table cell is saved to `NSUserDefaults` and when the aplication restarts I want to set the seleced cell as it was before. However, this causes problems when I do it too early as the number of sections are unknown, i.e. the table hasn't loaded its data yet. So I decided to set it in the function `numberOfRowsInSection`, which works but I am sure is not the correct place to do this.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    int iNofRows = 0; //Default  

    // It is not great doing this here but....
    if(bSetDefaultSelection == YES)  
    {  
        bSetDefaultSelection = NO; // Stop recursion  
        **NSIndexPath* indexPath =  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(NSUInteger)l last_sel_row inSection:(NSUInteger)0];  
        [self selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO                                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];**  
    }  
    return iNofRows;  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the place you're looking for is

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;    
 // Called when the view has been fully transitioned onto the screen. Default does nothing
```

(See UIViewController for more information)
I've just debugged my app and that method is called after the one you've mentioned:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

In your case you'd have to write something like:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(NSUInteger)l last_sel_row inSection:(NSUInteger)0];
    [self selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for the reply. I thought nobody answered so much appreciate the effort. The solution with '(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animate' only works with UITableViewController but I am dealing with UITableView. 
But I decided to post a notification in my main controller that triggers the table to select and that works fine. 
Thanks again.